# Como calcular la fecha de un día anterior en java

Tags: java

Yo recibo como parámetro la fecha que me envían, pero esa fecha que yo recibo le quiero restar -1:

Ejemplo, recibo la fecha de hoy en este formato 20230331 a esta fecha le quiero restar -1 para que al final me quede la fecha así 20230330, adjunto código de como lo tengo actualmente:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date dateFecha = simpleDateFormat.parse(date); --- date lo recibo como parametro
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd")
String fecha = dateFormat.format(dateFecha);
```

Se puede restar -1 al date format ?

Saludos

Comment: El dateformat es una plantilla para dar formato. Lo que manipulas es el Date, que es el que tiene métodos para este fin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos usar `java.util.Calendar` para realizar cálculos de tiempo. Entonces restar un día a una fecha dada queda así:

```
    var date = new Date(); // o pasada como parámetro
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    var ayer = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(ayer);
```

Comment: Para efectos de lo que requiero me es muy útil el ejemplo de @GavilanPatagonico, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes, la clase **Date** está marcada como **deprecated**, osea que salvo que sea absolutamente necesario, hay que evitar su uso.
Para reemplazarla podemos usar la clase **LocalDate**.
Pero antes vamos con el primer obstáculo, nos dices que recibes una fecha con el siguiente formato: 20230331, suponiendo que sea una cadena, y dado que ningún constructor aceptará como entrada esa cadena, debes convertirla a un formato compatible.

```
String entrada = "20230331";
String fecha = entrada.substring( 0,4 ) + "-" +
               entrada.substring( 4,6 ) + "-" +
               entrada.substring( 6,8 );
```

Luego construyes el objeto:

```
LocalDate dia = LocalDate.parse( fecha );
```

Si quieres restar un día:

```
diaAnterior = dia.plusDays( -1 );
```

Ahora veamos, si tienes una entrada distinta.

```
entrada = "2023-01-01";
dia = LocalDate.parse( entrada );
```

El anterior formato, es el que acepta como default la clase **LocalDate**.
Si lo que recibimos está en otro formato:

```
entrada = "01/01/2023";
DateTimeFormatter dateformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse( entrada, dateformatter );
```

Edición, gracias a la corrección de @GavilanPatagonico, descubro que se puede construir un objeto fecha a partir de la cadena "20230331", usando como **pattern** la cadena "**yyyyMMdd**", osea:

```
String entrada = "20230331";
DateTimeFormatter dateformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMdd" );
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse( entrada, dateformatter );
```

Comment: No es necesario convertir 20230331 usando Strings. Fijate que si hacés `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");` entonces se puede parsear usando `LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse( entrada, formatter );`

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico, mil gracias por la corrección/enseñanza.